# How can I center this rather uneven parent node around its dashes?

Tags: forest, trees

[image: A very simple tree with a rather uneven, i.e., not properly centred, parent node.]

[image: A screenshot of the TeX file for the tree in question]

My question is: given the tree in question, how can I centre its parent node around its dashes?

This is a sample of a much bigger, and complex, genealogical tree I am trying to build.

I would very much appreciate an answer.

You can find below the source code.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges, for tree={grow=north}
 [AAAAA --- BBB
    [A ]
    [B ]
    [C ]
    [D ]
    [E ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make root text even around dashed by use of `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges, for tree={grow=north}
 [AAAAA --- BBB\hphantom{BB}
    [A ]
    [B ]
    [C ]
    [D ]
    [E ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick, @Zarko. Very much appreciated. Thanks!